# Not able to get HashMap value in android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, hashmap

I am not able to get the value stored in the HashMap via log. It is showing 0.
I am trying to get the documents which have been created by the current user and in that document get the fields namely amount and locate. And then store them in the hashmap.

**Analyze.kt**

```
class Analyze : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_analyze)
        supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        val hashMap : HashMap<String, Int> = HashMap()
        hashMap["Travel"] = 0
        hashMap["Grocery"] = 0
        hashMap["Food"] = 0
        hashMap["One Time Cost"] = 0
        hashMap["Entertainment"] = 0
        hashMap["Other Cost"] = 0

        val db = Firebase.firestore
        val myCollectionRef = db.collection("posts")
        val user = Firebase.auth.currentUser
        val uid = user?.uid
        myCollectionRef.get().addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
            for (document in documents) {
                val id = document.getString("uid")
                if(id==uid){
                    val amount = document.getString("amount")?.let { Integer.parseInt(it) }
                    val locate = document.getString("locate").toString()
                    if (hashMap.containsKey(locate)) {
                        val count = hashMap[locate] ?: 0
                        hashMap[locate] = count + amount!!
                    } else {
                        hashMap[locate] = amount!!
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        val c = hashMap["Travel"]
        Log.d("success1", "message $c")
        val e = hashMap["Food"]
        Log.d("success2", "message $e")
    }
}
```

It should print the total sum of Travel and it should also print total sum of Food in the log.

Comment: There is no way you can do that. Firebase API is asynchronous. So please check the duplicate to see how can you solve this using a callback. You might also be interested in reading this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953).

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is that you are trying to access hashmap before it gets filled from Firebase, try to put logs or any other operations related to Hashmap inside `addOnSuccessListener`

```
myCollectionRef.get().addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
        for (document in documents) {
            val id = document.getString("uid")
            if(id==uid){
                val amount = document.getString("amount")?.let { Integer.parseInt(it) }
                val locate = document.getString("locate").toString()
                if (hashMap.containsKey(locate)) {
                    val count = hashMap[locate] ?: 0
                    hashMap[locate] = count + amount!!
                } else {
                    hashMap[locate] = amount!!
                }
            }
        }
        val c = hashMap["Travel"]
        Log.d("success1", "message $c")
        val e = hashMap["Food"]
        Log.d("success2", "message $e")
    }
```

Comment: Still not working. Its showing 0 and 0.

Comment: @AjaySatpati have you tried logging/debugging in your success listener to make sure you're actually getting values for `documents` and that they contain `"Travel"` and `"Food"` keys with values for `amount`? Remember the lookup is case-sensitive